# Ubuntu upgrade stopped at d/p/fix_rewrite_rule.patch

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, upgrade

While running apt-get dist-upgrade the server stopped at this lines:

```
apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.6) trusty; urgency=medium
* d/p/fix_rewrite_rule.patch: Add a configurable option to keep mod_dir from
:
```

Tried a second time but still got the same output.  The colon at the end, is it asking for input?  Pressing Enter does nothing.

It's using Nginx but this update is for Apache. What to do next?

The server is Ubuntu 14.04.2 on Amazon EC2.